# Regression models with variables from different unit of analyses

Tags: regression, mixed-model, multilevel-analysis

This has been a question I have been wondering about for quite some time.

What is the procedure for including variables into a regression that describe different units of analysis?

For example, take the example data below:

```
   Unit1 Unit2         X        Y  C1
1      1     A  8.069306 29.56817  50
2      2     A 57.374125 37.17405  50
3      3     A 28.610334 10.74725  50
4      4     A 11.655329 35.20314  50
5      5     A 55.010888 71.75909  50
6      6     B 86.169210 67.26364 100
7      7     B 96.723271 50.80567 100
8      8     B 80.706313 26.84097 100
9      9     B 91.193207 92.08061 100
10    10     B  3.991037 58.70960 100
```

`X` and `Y` refer to values for `Unit1`. `C1` refers to values for `Unit2`.

Where, for example, `Unit1` refers to individual-level responses and `Unit2` are state-level indicators.

This regression equation seems somewhat problematic, given I have repeating values in `C1`.

```
Y = a + b(X) + b(C1)
```

Are repeating values problematic in the regression model? If so, is there a standard approach to dealing with variables describing different units of analyses?

Comment: What are "units"?

Comment: Units refer to unit of analyses. For example, say Unit 1 are individual-level responses and unit 2 are state-level indicators.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Welcome to the site, Sharif. This is exactly what multilevel or mixed effects models are used for. You have variables `X` and `Y` measured on individual units (`Unit1`) and variable `C1` on group units (`Unit2`).

The multilevel model partitions the outcome `Y` into variance that is within `Unit2` groups and variance that is between `Unit2` groups, and this can be clearly seen in the model equation:

Level 1: $y_{ij} = \beta_{0j} + \beta1X_{ij} + \epsilon_{ij}$

Level 2: $\beta_{0j} = \gamma_{00} + \gamma_{01}C1_j + u_{0j}$

This model is also called a mixed model, and you can see where this terminology comes from by substituting the level 2 model into the level 1 model:

$y_{ij} = \gamma_{00} + \gamma_{01}C1_j + \beta1X_{ij} + (\epsilon_{ij} + u_{0j})$

Note that two error terms are assumed to be normally-distributed with $\epsilon_{ij}$ ~ $N(0, \sigma^2_0)$ and $u_{0j}$ ~ $N(0, \sigma^2_{u0})$.

By using the multilevel or mixed effects modeling framework, repeating values of `C1` are not a problem and are handled accordingly. Likewise, the random intercept $\beta_{0j}$ accounts for correlation in the outcome from getting repeated measures of `Y` on individual-level units (`Unit1`) within the same `Unit2`.

Comment: Awesome! Thank you so much for your helpful response. Do you have an R package you prefer to use when using multilevel or mixed effects?

Comment: `lme4` is my default. It handles many complicated models and has an ecosystem of packages that work well in conjunction with it. But also worth looking at are `nlme`, `GLMMadaptive`, and the `glmmTMB` packages. If you are interested in running Bayesian version of these models, `rstanarm` and `brms` are also great.

Comment: Excellent! Your recommendations are extremely helpful! Thank you so much again.